# Why doesn't ROUND(23/6) = 4 in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Case A**: When you are trying to round the result yourself to the nearest decimal

```
SELECT  ROUND   (3.833333333333333) --  4
```

**Case B**: When you let SQL do the math and then round to the nearest decimal

```
SELECT  ROUND   (23/6)          --  3   (OR CEIL)
```

In this case according to the order of operations:

> > SQL will divide what’s between the parenthesis, first = 3.833333333333333

> > And then (This is the problem) it will erase everything in the decimal places. (Converting it to int, automatically) =3.0

> > Now, let's round the decimals (Which are already erased in the previous step! And now it’s = 0)

> > So, the last result will be (3). Not (4).!

**Even with conversions:**

```
SELECT  CAST (DIV (23,6)    AS NUMERIC (10,5))  AS  tst -- 3.00000
```

```
SELECT  CAST ((23/6)     AS DECIMAL (5,2))      AS  tst -- 3.00
```

```
SELECT  CAST (23/6  AS FLOAT)           AS  tst -- 3
```

```
SELECT  CAST (23/6  AS REAL)            AS  tst -- 3
```

**Is there a solution to this problem ?**

Comment: Don't have access to test right now, but try `SELECT  ROUND   (23.0/6)`-  I suspect you're doing integer division

Comment: `(23/6)` is doing integer division, `round(cast(23 as float)/6)` or `round(23/6.)`

Comment: Thank you very much, Allan. Done

Comment: Thank you, dnoeth. Another pretty way.

Comment: Or `select round(23::float / 6)` or `select round(23 / 6::float)`, etc. In summary, make either numerator or denominator into `float`, and it forces the entire expression into `float`, which removes the quirks of the integer division.

Comment: Casting as a `float` feels inherently uncomfortable to deliberately add a less specific unit type to get the correct result from a specific mathematics problem. Float is not a fraction-specific unit type such as `decimal`. Can you cast the devision as a `Decimal` instead?

Comment: Must be issue with PostgreSQL because SQL in Access returns 4 from Round(23/6). However, Round(15/6) returns 2 instead of 3 because of bankers (even/odd) rounding.

Comment: Thanks, Timur, For making it more clearer.

Comment: Yes indeed, Martin. Let's say
```
SELECT CAST(23 AS DECIMAL(2,0)) / 6
```
Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it performs integer division. When then engine evaluates:

```
ROUND (23/6)
```

the expression `23/6` is evaluated first as `3`. Then:

```
ROUND (3)
```

is evaluated as `3`.

If you want the float precision you can multiply by `1.0`. For example by doing:

```
ROUND ( 1.0 * 23/6)
```

Comment: Thank you, The Impaler, for your time and effort.